# how can I understand spin fluctuation in iron based superconductors?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, strong-correlated

In study of iron based superconductors, one of the starting point is that electrons are weakly interacting(or weakly correlated) such that we can still apply many body perturbation theory(so called weak coupling scenario by A.Chubukov, for instance). According to them, nesting give rises to SDW(itinerant) and superconductivity appears by doping from SDW. More importantly, superconducting interaction between cooper pair is mediated by so called "spin fluctuation", the collective bosonic degrees of freedom.
Can anyone give more clear and simple picture for spin fluctuation?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 4) If you get a satisfactory answer, remember to accept it by clicking on the green checkmark.

Comment: In general, I believe that the key to understand these fluctuations, is to have an insight into how fluctuation-dissipation theorem works and how excitations determine ground state correlation. Unfortunately, I do not know anything about pnictides, so I will have to eagerly wait detailed answer to this question.

Comment: @Giovanni, do you have a more specific question in mind? Are you asking what spin fluctuations are? Or how they arise in pnictides in particular? Or how they give rise to superconductivity?